# Getting Cursors.AppStarting in Win32 or MFC?

Tags: winapi, mfc, cursor

Is it possible to get the .NET `Cursors.AppStarting` using a MFC or Win32 function?

Someting similar to the `CWaitCursor` but indicating background processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Win32:

```
// show the app starting cursor
HCURSOR hPrevCursor = SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_APPSTARTING));

// restore the original cursor when done
SetCursor(hPrevCursor);
```

Check out the documentation for [LoadCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453410.aspx) and [SetCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648393(VS.85).aspx). Also check out [this note](http://www.petterhesselberg.com/hourglass.html) regarding the nuances of restoring the original cursor.